# UITableViewCell change on height constraint and autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have three two subviews inside cell contentview. I have height constraint for both of the subviews. Depending on flag I want to hide either of the view. For this i have changed height constraint.
 It is not changing the cell height. How can I change the cell height.[image]

Comment: You will have to set a property, or create a data structure(Dictionary or Array) to hold a reference to the cells you want at a different height and use `func tableView(UITableView, heightForRowAt: IndexPath)` which is part of the UITableViewDelegate, and UITableView's `func reloadRows(at: [IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation)`

Comment: Can't it be done using autolayout and automatic dimension